# NullPointerException on setMenuVisibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm following the next tutorial to insert a tab http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/. My problem is that I'm trying to insert it in a fragment not in an activity, but I'm getting the next error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(boolean)' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:943)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1157)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1283)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2658)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18797)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at an...
```

The fragment that contains the tabhost and the viewpager is the next:

```
public class AdministrarFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "AdministrarFragment";
    private FragmentIterationListener mCallback = null;
    public interface FragmentIterationListener{
        public void onFragmentIteration(Bundle parameters);
    }

    public static AdministrarFragment newInstance(Bundle arguments){
        AdministrarFragment f = new AdministrarFragment();
        if(arguments != null){
            f.setArguments(arguments);
        }
        return f;
    }

    public AdministrarFragment(){

    }

    //El fragment se ha adjuntado al Activity
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity activity = context instanceof Activity ? (Activity) context : null;
    }

    //El Fragment ha sido quitado de su Activity y ya no está disponible
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    //La vista ha sido creada y cualquier configuración guardada está cargada
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    }

    //El Activity que contiene el Fragment ha terminado su creación
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    //El fragment se ha adjuntado al Activity
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        mCallback = (FragmentIterationListener) activity;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_administrar, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tiempo)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.gastos)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final AdministrarPageAdapter adapter = new AdministrarPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

And this is my pageadapter:

```
public class AdministrarPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public AdministrarPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                AdministrarTiemposFragment tab_tiempos = new AdministrarTiemposFragment();
                return tab_tiempos;
            /*case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;*/
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Miight not solve your problem, but instead of passing a NumOfTabs. I think you should either pass a list of your fragments and then use that to get the item at position, and also return the size of that list in getCount(). 

Or always initialise an empty list in the constructor and have an addFragment(Fragment fragment) in the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done something like this instead. Might not solve the problem but try it out, since probably your switch:default is called.
Fragments in the list should be added in the order you want them to show.

```
public class AdministrarPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        List<Fragment> mFragments;

        public AdministrarPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.mFragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }
    }
```

In your fragment, initialise the list before the adapter

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
fragments.add(new AdministrarTiemposFragment());    

final AdministrarPageAdapter adapter = new AdministrarPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or have a method on the adapter that add fragments into a list that is initialised in the adapters contructor.

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);  
final AdministrarPageAdapter adapter = new AdministrarPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new AdministrarTiemposFragment());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It's sounds good, but how I can initialize the list in the main fragment? I was calling it like final AdministrarPageAdapter adapter = new AdministrarPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());